# $x^3+y^3<1<x+y \implies (x,y)\in{]0,1[}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

We have :

$H$ is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^3+y^3<1<x+y\}$.

How can one show that  the set $H$ is included in  ${]0,1[}\times{]0,1[}$ ?

We have :

$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)<1<x+y$

Im stuck here !

Comment: Your notation is very strange...

Comment: A visualisation in desmos graph, just to help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hx00a7rvhd .
Doesn't this give some ideas ? ;-)

Comment: @Integral what do you mean by strange ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to represent with your symbols. If you don't know MathJax, write out the concepts in words, for example, "$H$ is the set of pairs on some rectangle etc.", which I think is what you're trying to do.

Comment: @integral It's a very common notation for open intervals, especially in French speaking countries.

Comment: @GFauxPas Same comment.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi He wrote $C(]0;1[$ x $]0;1[)$. I do know the notation $]0,1[$ for open intervals, but not that $C$ and not the $;$ instead $,$

Comment: @Integral NajibIdrissi right ! I live in a frensh speaking language

Comment: As fair as I know, the french notation is $]0,1[\times ]0,1[$, and not $C(]0;1[$x$]0;1[)$. Take a look at the edition history. By the way, the question as it is know, was edited by me, I do know the french notation.

Comment: C and € here obviously represent $\in$ .

Comment: @user233658: did you saw my answer above ?

Comment: Now this C makes sense ^^ but why use ; instead , ? This has nothing to do with french notation. And just to makes things clear, from the very beginning, my complaint about the notation had nothing to do with the symbols ] and [, but that C and the use  of ; instead ,

Comment: @Integral: in french, decimal point is already noted ',' ...
Seriously, you really can't read usernnn's question ?

Comment: For future reference, use `{]0,1[}` instead of `]0,1[` in the LaTeX. Otherwise, the spacing is weird.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \le 0$, you have $y > 1-x \ge 1$. But then $$1 > x^3+y^3 > x^3 +(1-x)^3=1-3x+3x^2 \ge 1.$$ You get a similar contradiction is you suppose $x \ge 1$ as this implies $y<0$ as $x^3+y^3 < 1$.

Comment: Can u explain more the seconde step

Comment: What do you name the second step? Please type the precise equality / inequality with which you have an issue.

Comment: @user233658: He used the fact that $1<x+y\iff y>1-x$.